# How to get country name using geocode?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, google-maps, geocode

I want to use geocode to get current country name where the site is loaded.

I have to store country name in session. Also have a JavaScript to find out country name but I used jsp pages so it won't allow to store JavaScript variable in JSP session. In geocode GClientGeocoder() class is there. But how to get address from it?

Comment: Are you trying to get the end-user's country? I'm not sure GClientGeocoder does that. You might need something like http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location or http://hostip.info. Or are you trying to get the country name of an address you have localised to your end users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of geocode I used Locale class of java in jsp which gives default country.

Answer (score 0):

You use this lib.

Java IP (InetAddress) Locator
http://sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_javainetlocator/